# Cannot get response header fetch request even with Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch

I am trying to get the `x-total-count` response header from a fetch JS request, I have included `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` as advised in other previous posts and I am still unable to get the response header, I can see it is being received in chrome dev tools and have tried `response.headers.get('x-total-count');` and iterating over `response.headers` with no luck.

What am I missing here?

```
async function postData() { 
      const myPost = {
          "listingType":"Sale",
          "propertyTypes": [
              "townhouse",
              "duplex",
              "semiDetached",
              "studio",
              "townhouse",
              "villa",
              "ApartmentUnitFlat",
              "Rural",
              "house"
            ],
          "geoWindow": {
            "box": {
              "topLeft": {
                "lat": aNorth,
                "lon": aWest
              },
              "bottomRight": {
                "lat": aSouth,
                "lon": aEast
              }
            },
          },
          "pageNumber": pageNumber,
          "pageSize": 100
        }
        
        const options = {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(myPost),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-API-Key": "API-KEY",
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'x-total-count'
          }
        };

        const response = await fetch('https://api.domain.com.au/v1/listings/residential/_search', options)
        if (!response.ok) {
          const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
          throw new Error(message);
        }

        const totalCount = response.headers.get('x-total-count');

        for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) { console.log(pair[0]+ ': '+ pair[1]); }

        console.log(totalCount)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an updated I contacted the team that runs this API and received the following response below, turns out it was an issue on their end.

> It would appear you've run into an issue with our early support for
> CORS requests, the header you are trying to set,
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers, is actually one that we specify from
> our side.
>
> Presently we don't specify it completely, so the x-total-count header
> is not exposed to browsers which follow the CORS rules.
>
> I have added this issue to our backlog to be rectified as soon as
> possible, and it will most likely will be part of our first planned
> update in early January 2021.